# Does mysqldump export indices, by default?

Tags: mysql, index, mysqldump, myisam, export

I played around a little with mysqldump and I was wondering, if it does export indices (`FULLTEXT`, `INDEX`,...) by default. I [read up on it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html) and I found [this option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_disable-keys):

```
--disable-keys, -K
```

which suggests, that it actually does export the indices. But I don't want to trust my interpretation and I want to make sure I got it right (or wrong ;-)). Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Please refresh. I updated my answer with example mysqldump excerpts.

Comment: Please refresh. I updated my answer with an additional caveat about DISABLE KEYS and ENABLE KEYS.

Comment: Please refresh. I updated my answer with an additional caveats about bypassing DISABLE KEYS and dumping tablespaces.

Comment: This question deserves a +1 because I am almost certain many have had this same question in mind but was afraid to ask. You asked, you get the +1 !!!

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: You put a lot of effort in your answer. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it does not export indexes. Indexes are rebuilt upon loading the mysqldump back into mysql. The options you found "--disable-keys" cause the the mysqldump to write something like this before the table's load via INSERTs:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tblAccountLinks`;
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
CREATE TABLE `tblAccountLinks` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `FirmNo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `CustomerNo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `AccountNo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `LinkType` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `AccessLevel` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `Status` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27023 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblAccountLinks`
--

LOCK TABLES `tblAccountLinks` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tblAccountLinks` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `tblAccountLinks` VALUES (1,'F0001','C001','T00000001',1,2,1,'2008-06-30 07:55:43'),(2,'
F0001','C001','T00000002',2,2,1,'2008-06-30 07:55:43'),(3,'F0001','C002','27601012',1,2,1,'2008-06-3 ...
```

The line after LOCK TABLES is

```
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tblAccountLinks` DISABLE KEYS */;
```

This is what the --disable-keys option embeds in the mysqldump.

Also, this is embedded after all the INSERTs are done

```
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tblAccountLinks` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

CAVEAT #1

> DISABLE KEYS and ENABLE KEYS were
>   implemented to disable the reloading
>   of nonunique indexes while a table is
>   being reloaded. Primary Keys and
>   Unique Keys are not disabled. They are
>   loaded at the same moment the INSERTs
>   are being. Once you ENABLE KEYS, the
>   nonunique indexes are rebuilt via
>   sorting (or using the MyISAM key cache is there isn't
>   enough available memory)
>
> Unfortunately, DISABLE KEYS and ENABLE
>   KEYS only work for MyISAM tables, not
>   InnoDB.

CAVEAT #2

You do not have to --disable-keys. You could disable DISABLE KEYS (no pun intended) them with --skip-disable-keys:

```
  -K, --disable-keys  '/*!40000 ALTER TABLE tb_name DISABLE KEYS */; and
                      '/*!40000 ALTER TABLE tb_name ENABLE KEYS */; will be put
                      in the output.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-disable-keys to disable.)
```

This could result in a slower load and a potential lopsiding of the index pages for nonunique indexes.

CAVEAT #3

You can dump the actual InnoDB tablespaces (MySQL 5.5.12)

```
  -Y, --all-tablespaces 
                      Dump all the tablespaces.
  -y, --no-tablespaces 
                      Do not dump any tablespace information.
```

Comment: Please note this is out of date, MySQL 5.7 does include indexes.